# in alexa developer console how to get the client id and client secret access key to be used in proactive api

Tags: python-2.7, alexa-skills-kit

i am making a project on notifications sent by alexa,how to get the client id and client secret access in it?Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3hnj.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open [developer console](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask?) then your skill and go to Permissions tab (on the left hand side in the bottom).

You'll find them in Alexa Skill Messaging section.

[image]

Comment: i am not able to see the alexa skill mesaging section do i need to enable it elsewhere

Comment: pfa the screenshot

Comment: according to https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/authenticate-a-customer-permissions.html#steps-for-asynchronous-message-authentication this section should appear when you change something in permissions (try change Reminders switch for example)